# Spring Social Facebook get album is giving 0 result

Tags: spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I want to get all the photos posted by user in facebook using spring social facebook.
I am able to get connected and able to retrieve user name and id, but when i am trying to retrieve album of photos, i am getting zero result . I tried using FQL operations and graph api.
following is my code which i am using for getting album.

```
PagedList<Album> albums = facebook.mediaOperations().getAlbums();
        System.out.println(facebook.mediaOperations().toString());
        System.out.println(facebook.GRAPH_API_URL);

        // System.out.println(albums.size());
        // List<Photo> images = new ArrayList<Photo>();
        // for (Album album : albums) {
        // images.addAll(facebook.mediaOperations().getPhotos(album.getId()));
        // }

        String query = "SELECT pid, src, src_small, src_big, caption FROM photo WHERE owner= me()";

        List<Image> images = facebook.fqlOperations().query(query,
                new FqlResultMapper<Image>() {

                    public Image mapObject(FqlResult result) {

                        Image image = new Image();
                        image.setPid(result.getString("pid"));
                        image.setSrc(result.getString("src"));
                        image.setSrc_small(result.getString("src_small"));
                        image.setSrc_big(result.getString("src_big"));

                        return image;

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried something just now similar to the commented code you have and it worked fine for me. I ended up receiving all of the photos for the authorized user in all of that user's albums.

Is it possible that the user doesn't have "user_photos" permission? Or...maybe no albums/photos? Or possibly, the permissions for those albums and/or photos are set so that applications can't see them via the API?